# How to send a big array (96000 samples) to the ESP32 serial-port via MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, arduino, serial-port, arduino-c++

In short, I am reading a .wav file in MATLAB for the purposes of sending it to the ESP32 for an FFT analysis. The .wav file in question contains a recording of a Corona effect. My file has 96223 samples when inputted into MATLAB.

For now, I am trying to just get back a checksum so I can know that the data is sent correctly.

I have already tried using the code I've written for smaller sample sizes. For example, I get back the correct checksum when I send 200 samples although the code takes longer than I want it to take which is not good. More than that though, and I never get anything back because of timeouts.

This is my MATLAB code:

```matlab
esp = serial('COM3');
set(esp, 'DataBits' , 8);
set(esp, 'StopBits', 1);
set(esp, 'BaudRate', 9600);
set(esp, 'Parity', 'none');
set(esp, 'terminator', 'LF');

%filename = 'test100.wav';
%corona = audioread(filename);

load('corona')
fopen(esp);
pause(0.1)
for i = 1:200
   fprintf(esp, '%5.9f\n', corona(i,1)); 
   pause(0.1);       
end
output = fscanf(esp, '%f\n') %read the checksum
fclose(instrfind);
```

And this is my Arduino code:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
float sentData[200]; //initialize data array
int i = 0;
const int ledPin = 26;
float checksum = 0;
int CNT = 0;

void printFloat(float value, int places);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  while (Serial.available() < 200)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); //keep the LED on while the data is being sent
  }

  while (Serial.available() != 0)
  {
    sentData[i] = Serial.parseFloat(); //parse the data to the array
    i++;
  }
  Serial.flush();
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); //turn off the LED when data is fully parsed

  for (size_t x = 0; x < 200; ++x)
  {
    checksum += sentData[x]; //calculate the sum of all elements in the sentData array
  }
  printFloat(checksum, 10); //send the checksum to the serial port for reading
}
void loop()
{
}

void printFloat(float value, int places)
{
  // this is used to cast digits
  int digit;
  float tens = 0.1;
  int tenscount = 0;
  int i;
  float tempfloat = value;

  // if this rounding step isn't here, the value  54.321 prints as 54.3209

  // calculate rounding term d:   0.5/pow(10,places)
  float d = 0.5;
  if (value < 0)
    d *= -1.0;
  // divide by ten for each decimal place
  for (i = 0; i < places; i++)
    d /= 10.0;
  tempfloat += d;

  // first get value tens to be the large power of ten less than value

  if (value < 0)
    tempfloat *= -1.0;
  while ((tens * 10.0) <= tempfloat)
  {
    tens *= 10.0;
    tenscount += 1;
  }

  // write out the negative if needed
  if (value < 0)
    Serial.print('-');

  if (tenscount == 0)
    Serial.print(0, DEC);

  for (i = 0; i < tenscount; i++)
  {
    digit = (int)(tempfloat / tens);
    Serial.print(digit, DEC);
    tempfloat = tempfloat - ((float)digit * tens);
    tens /= 10.0;
  }

  // if no places after decimal, stop now and return
  if (places <= 0)
    return;

  // otherwise, write the point and continue on
  Serial.print('.');

  // now write out each decimal place by shifting digits one by one into the ones place and writing the truncated value
  for (i = 0; i < places; i++)
  {
    tempfloat *= 10.0;
    digit = (int)tempfloat;
    Serial.print(digit, DEC);
    // once written, subtract off that digit
    tempfloat = tempfloat - (float)digit;
  }
}
```

I expected to get back a checksum but I get a timeout when using very large sample sizes. I should also add that even though the ESP32 should be able to handle my file, I can't just push the whole file into the serial port because I get a buffer overflow error. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Bump up that communication speed! At 9600bps you'll take ages to transfer anything. With an FTDI usb to serial converter which support high speed, I communicate between PC (matlab) and 8 bit micro (8051) at 3,000,000bps and it works like a charm. I am sure you can at least use 115200bps with a standard usb to serial adapter.

Comment: Also it seems weird for me to use a `float` data type for a checksum. The float rounding errors could be different on the two platforms and the checksum might not match even with similar inputs. I would rather use a integral type (`uint32` for example) for the checksum, and do the checksum on a byte by byte level rather than on an exotic [4 bytes] data type.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will look into the adapter although that will only help me while writing the code and testing, I can't use it for the actual project that I'd like in the end (don't want to bore you with the details). Good tip on the checksum, I'll try your idea.

Answer (score 1):

First `%5.9f` doesn't make sense to me.

Thats minimum 5 characters with 9 digit precision. That 5 doesn't make sense as you'll always have at least 11 characters with 9 digit precision

Then let me do some maths for you:

96000 samples, 12 characters each (including `\n`) is a total of 10368000 bits.

At 9600 baud that's 1080 seconds of transfer time. -> 18 minutes.

As you add 0.1s pause after each sample you add another 9600 seconds to that.

Which leaves you with a total of 178 minutes (3 hours) of transfer time.

What do you expect?

For 200 samples its still 22,25s.

Comment: The ESP32 can easily support up to 115200 baudrate as far as I know. So I'll test this out. I ideally would like 20 digits precision. Is it possible to do this with an acceptable speed?

Comment: @user3601507 your biggest issue is the pause in matlab. remove that. ESP8266 is capable of several megabits. if your connection is good. 9600 is used for low quality connections, when reliability is more important than speed

Comment: I removed it and it still works. I am getting this error though: Warning: Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached.. I used to get this before but I ignored it, however it doesn't seem to make sense because I'm getting the desired result at 200 samples at least.

Comment: I edited my comment immediately after I accidentally pressed enter mid-way through. Don't know how you managed to read it so fast and respond before I edited it.

Comment: @user3601507 I'm just too fast for this world. serial is [not recommended](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.html?s_tid=doc_ta). try serialport and see if you still have problems.

Comment: This only works in 2019b correct? I will have to get the newer version of MATLAB and try again. I will update this question if needed.

Comment: `serial` is not recommended **starting in R2019b**. If you are using an older version of MATLAB then using `serial` is fine (not that you have a choice anyway).